# Plus/minus symbol in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, eps

I'm generating .eps figures in gnuplot for inclusion into papers typeset with LaTeX, using

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced "Helvetica" 14
```

This generally works perfectly, but i'm now trying to put together a figure using a label that includes a ± symbol. If I use it directly, e.g.

```
set label "-56±2"
```

then it appears correctly on the default 'wxt' terminal but is prefixed by an A with a circumflex (i.e. -56Â±2) in the postscript output. Using

```
set label "-56^+/-2"
```

works but looks rubbish. In the past i've used the 'Angstrom' character (Å) by doing

```
set encoding iso_8859_1 
set xlabel "wavelength (\305)"
```

but I haven't managed to get this to work either for the unicode representation of ± which I think is \261 (see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b1/index.htm), i.e.

```
set label "-56 \261 2"
```

but I just get an empty space between the -56 and 2. Any ideas on how to do this? Ubuntu 10.10 and Gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 0, if it's important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the record, from the Gnuplot perspective the correct answer does appear to be this:

```
set encoding iso_8859_1 
set label "-56 \261 2"
```

which gives a label

```
-56 ± 2
```

It works perfectly on a different machine (same Gnuplot level) so i'm not sure why there's an issue on the original Ubuntu machine; both machines display the resultant .eps file correctly.

Answer (score 2):

To get a more beautiful label, I suggest epslatex terminal. It produces graph part in eps format and text part in latex format. Then you can edit your tex file and inset any special characters latex support.